# Codewars constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am stuck on a Javascript challenge from codewars.com. It looks to be a constructor(?) function, which I thought I knew but alas, no. 
I looked for examples on MDN and other places. 
I'd rather know the wrong points than the straight answer, to see if I can figure myself.
The challenge:

```
function new Person(name){
  this.name = name;
  return name;
}
Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
};
```

By doing some research I thought maybe adding to the constructor for both names would do it but again getting an "unexpected token new" error. My attempt:

```js
function new Person(name, otherName){
  this.name = name;
  this.otherName = otherName;
  return name + " " + otherName;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
};
var fullName = new Person("Fred", "Jones");
greet.fullName();
```

Patience with my ignorance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
pychap

Comment: Please read [ask]. There isn't a proper problem statement here nor is there a specific question

Comment: Just start googling for *javascript factory pattern*, try it out and then come back with a more consistent example. We'll be happy to help you then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have tried is quite wrong, but rather than give you the code (since you are trying to learn it), I will give you some pointers.

the `new` keyword cannot be used after a `function` declaration. It is used to create a new instance of a method `new Person()`

Within the `greet` method, `name` is not defined. You will need to use the proper scope to get the name.

`greet.fullName()` isn't defined either, what you want is to access the methods of the `fullName` variable.

Comment: Also contstructor functions generally shouldn't return anything.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName){ //declaration of function named person taking 2 arguments
  this.firstName = firstName; //creating variable holding firstName
  this.lastName = lastName; //same as above but for lastName
//removed return as constructor functions shouldnt return anything, you call this function with 'new' which already creats content of your object
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(){ //this is another declaration but for greet function. You can think about it like a function you can call but only for variables holding Person object
  return "Hi " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; //use 'this' to tell your program to work on object that calls this function (greet())
};

var fullName = new Person("Fred", "Jones"); //this is point of your program - in variable fullName it creates an object using your function Person. Since now all methods that has Person you can call on fullName variable.
console.log(fullName.greet()); // here I use console.log to print resutl of fullName.greet() call. I defined fullName and I have put object into it created with Person function. Now I place fullName first, then calling one of methods it owns - greet(). Result is sentence defined in greet declaration.
```

edited: Placed explanations in comments

Comment: Downvote because all you did was supply the code to fix it, without any explanation on why this fixes it

Comment: Ah ok then, I will explain what happens. Going edit.

Comment: Why did you remove the `return` statement from the `Person()` function? I know the answer, but you need to explain it in the answer.